# IE doesn't recognize Enter/Return Button on submit

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, submit

I am having a little trouble with this, I am submitting a login form in my code, it is working fine on FF and Chrome, but not properly on IE (on IE it is submitting the form only if I go with the mouse over the login button and click it with the mouse pointer, it is not working when I try to hit the Enter/Return Button)

Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms['logon'].submit();">Login</a>
<input type="image" class="hidden" onclick="document.forms['logon'].submit();" />
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There should be javascript error

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Enter should trigger the first `input[type=submit]` element. Image inputs are supposed to submit the coordinates where you clicked, so I'm not entirely sure how Firefox and Chrome manage to submit it with the Enter key...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I figured it out changing the type from image to submit and some css changes, thanks anyway